# Order by multiple column first with alphabet then numbers

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, db2-400

trying to convert DB2 query ORDER BY condition into SQL Server

DB2 Query

```
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(CorpName))) > 1 THEN CorpVal Else '999' END,
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(FName,1,1) != '*' THEN FName Else '999'  END
```

SQL Query

```
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN CorpName like '[a-z]%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
CASE WHEN FName like '[a-z]%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

I have the data something like

ABC,
24KS,
ABE,
AJX,
-Extra,
ABF,
1X1

I need the output like below

ABC,
ABE,
ABF,
AJX,
24KS,
1X1,
-Extra

this does not works for me, need some more suggestion.

Comment: The first query, the DB2 one, would work in SQL Server too though. `LEN`, `RTRIM`, `LTRIM`, and `SUBSTRING` are all functions in T-SQL too, and it also supports `CASE` expressions. If you have an expression that works, why change it?

Comment: Sample data would also help your question to be more understandable.

Comment: @Larnu I do agree and my thought was the same, but it is behaving differently, I mean in DB2 it working as expected but when using this condition in SQL server then its not working

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: @Larnu not working mean, not sorting.. so in DB2 data is sorting as ABC, PQR, 24KS and SQL Server it is showing 24KS, ABC, PQR

Comment: Well, `'24KS'` *is* before `'ABC'` when you sort those values, @Rocky . `'2'` has a "lower" value than `'A'` and thus `'24KS'` is "lower" than `'ABC'`. We really need that sample data and expected results you were asked for earlier.

Comment: Your tsql query is nothing like the your db2 query - especially if you are using a case-sensitive collation. Ignoring case and looking at just the first expression, your tsql logic sorts rows into 2 (and only 2) groups - those that start with letters and those that do not. That is NOT what your DB2 logic does. Just use the original logic as Larnu suggested - your translation failed.

Comment: If you want to visualize your errors, just add your two sort expressions as columns in your select list. You will see that you effectively sort by 2 values in each level - you never sort by the actual names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordering is determined by collations in [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-ver15) and [DB2](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=functions-collation-key). It seems your iSeries DB2 is configured with an EBCDIC collation so you could add an explict `COLLATE` clause to the `ORDER BY` expression to coerce EBCDIC ordering rules for SQL Server since your SQL Server collation is apparently different.

Below is an example of your original DB2 query with the clause added for the SQL Server:

```
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(CorpName))) > 1 THEN CorpVal Else '999' END COLLATE SQL_EBCDIC037_CP1_CS_AS,
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(FName,1,1) != '*' THEN FName Else '999'  END COLLATE SQL_EBCDIC037_CP1_CS_AS
```